# Clear undo/redo history from a callback in Plotly Dash

Tags: plotly-dash

Using Plotly Dash with `show_undo_redo=True`, the undo and redo buttons seems to work as expected most of the time.

However, at specific actions it becomes necessary to "clear history", i.e. to prevent users from going back past that specific action.

Can this be done?

One obvious way would be to reload the page, but I'm trying to avoid this.